# Writing entire dataframe to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to write this dataframe to a csv file. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import fnmatch
import re

path = "/home/sarah/verilator-dev/PyDev/cov_add/TotalCoverage"
file_list = os.listdir(path)


df_list = []
line_list = []
coverage_list = []
for file in file_list:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.info'): 
        filedata = open(file, 'r')
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for line in filedata:
            if x == 1 and line != "end_of_record\n":
                result = re.split(pattern = r"[:,]", string = line, maxsplit = 2)
                line_list.append(int(result[1]))
                coverage_list.append(int(result[2].strip('\n')))
            if line.startswith("SF:txuart.sv"):
                x = 1
                pass
            else:
                pass


data_tuples = list(zip(line_list,coverage_list))
df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Line','Coverage'])
byLine = df.groupby('Line')
df_final = byLine.sum()

f = open("output.csv", "at")

#write dataframe to file
df_final.to_csv('output.csv', columns = ['Line', 'Coverage'])
```

```
I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coverage-add.py", line 53, in <module>
    df_final.to_csv('output.csv', columns = ['Line', 'Coverage'])
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3387, in to_csv
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1064, in to_csv
    csv_formatter = CSVFormatter(
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.cols = self._initialize_columns(cols)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 144, in _initialize_columns
    self.obj = self.obj.loc[:, cols]
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 889, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1069, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_tuple_same_dim(tup)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 775, in _getitem_tuple_same_dim
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1113, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1053, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1266, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "/home/sarah/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1321, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['Line'], dtype='object'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback message. We shouldn't have to guess which line fails.

Comment: post the entire log

Answer (score 1):

Your will need to do `df_final = byLine.sum().reset_index()` to get your `Line` column back.

After you group by `Line` column, it is now index, and you try to reference it in `.to_csv()` method.

Comment: @sgdoc7 - but please do post the traceback message to keep this a high quality question.